# How do I add the reference to google translator in VB.net? The "Imports Google.Cloud.Translation.V2" gives me error

Tags: vb.net, google-translation-api

I'm trying to execute the next code but de "Import" statement gives me error. I have installed the Google Cloud SDK but I don't now how to add the missing reference un Visual Studio 2015.

This is the code:

```
Imports Google.Cloud.Translation.V2
Function GoogleTranslateV2Text(sourceText As String, sourceLang As String, targetLang As String) As String
    Try
      Dim TClient As TranslationClient = TranslationClient.Create()
      If sourceLang.ToUpper = targetLang.ToUpper Then
        Return (sourceText)
      End If
      Dim response = TClient.TranslateText(sourceText, targetLang, sourceLang)
      Dim result As String = response.TranslatedText
      Return result
    Catch ex As Exception
      Dim msg As String = "#1#: " & ex.Message
      Return msg
    End Try
  End Function
```

Comment: Add a reference for that google assembly to your project? Right click references in the solution explorer, select add reference, probably need to click the browse button, navigate to the desired folder(s) and assembly(ies) and add them?

Comment: If you just need the translation service, you don't need the SDK, you can just use the Cloud Console to get your Service Credentails (as a JSON). Follow the instructions here: [Setting up a .NET development environment](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/setup) and open [up the Console](http://console.cloud.google.com/) (in your Browser). Install (via NuGet Package Manager) the `Google.Cloud.Translation.V2` assemblies (you might need to update a lot of those after the first installation). **Do not** create a `x86` project (or leave `Prefer 32-Bit` checked in the project/compile panel).